# Сравнительный оборот или сравнительное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении "Ни у одного народа нет к своему поэту такой любви, как у нас, у русских" каким членом предложения является "как у нас, у русских", это сравнительный оборот или неполное придаточное предложение со значением сравнения? Как подчеркнуть этот оборот? Также непонятно, как подчеркнуть аналогичный оборот в предложении "Вода была теплая, как парное молоко" (была теплая какая? или как?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае мы видим **два интересных вопроса**, которые не всегда решаются однозначно и просто: (1) как различить сравнительный оборот и неполное придаточное сравнительное предложение; (2) как определить синтаксическую функцию оборота при грамматическом разборе.

1. Сравним два предложения: *Бросился бежать, как заяц.* *Бросился бежать, **как заяц*** (бегает) *от волка*.

**Условно считается,** что в первом случае у нас сравнительный оборот, а во втором случае – неполное сравнительное придаточное предложение (с пропущенным сказуемым).

В то же время в общем случае абсолютной границы между двумя конструкциями нет: мы имеем или сокращенное придаточное,  или расширенный сравнительный оборот.

2. *Ни у одного народа нет к своему поэту **такой любви, как у нас, у русских.***

Очевидно, что здесь у нас сравнительный оборот, причем он построен по образцу придаточного предложения с **местоименно-союзной связью** (определение + сравнение): ***такой** любви, как у нас, у русских.* Указательное слово подсказывает нам  функцию оборота: любви (какой?).

Это **несогласованное определение**, выраженное сравнительным оборотом (с дополнительным уточнением): **как у нас, у русских.**

3. *Вода была (какая?) теплая, **как парное молоко**.*

Сравнительные обороты могут быть различными членами предложения, в данном случае оборот входит **в именную часть сказуемого** как однородный член: *теплая, как парное молоко.*

Сравнить: *Вода была как парное молоко*. Здесь оборот является именной частью сказуемого.

Comment: Материал по первому предложению дан в соответствии с учебником для вузов "Синтаксис современного русского языка", 2013 года

Answer (score 1):

*Ни у одного народа нет к своему поэту такой любви, как у нас, у русских*

"Как у нас, у русских" — это сравнительный оборот, так как нет сказуемого или относящихся к нему второстепенных членов.